# Unity, scalling the width of a dynamically created Gameobject in a a scroll view content box

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to add 100 dynamically created buttons to a scroll view in Unity, but I have a problem letting the scroll view automatically adjust the width of the buttons to match the width of my screen.

When I tried to add the buttons manually it worked fine , but when I do this by code I get another results.

The code I am using :

```
public GameObject button;
public GameObject scrollviewcontents;

void Start()
{
    for (int i =0; i<=100;i++) {
  

       GameObject dbutton = Instantiate(button);
        dbutton.name = i.ToString();
        dbutton.transform.parent = scrollviewcontents.transform;
    }
```

}

and The results I get :
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBFB8.png)

[Results with comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYVjw.png)

**I just want the buttons to look like as they are added manually**, any help ???

Comment: Hello have you check the child force expand width in the parent of buttons vertical group script?

Comment: Yes , as you can see from the photo it is ticked

Comment: why scroll view is your parent it should be the content transform because it has the script.

Comment: the content transform is my parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when instantiating an object the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before. try this instead:

`dbutton.transform.SetParent(scrollviewcontents.transform, false);`

Comment: Thank you very Much , Worked Like a Charm